# Cannot connect to monitor via. Extron IN1806 Scaling Presentation Switcher

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, 22.04, hdmi

Goal: connect to monitor via. HDMI to **Extron IN1806 Scaling Presentation Switcher**.

I suspect I'm missing a driver.

Nothing appears under Settings > Screen Display - and the cursor cannot leave the laptop display.

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux ubuntu-pcs 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:75000000-75ffffff memory:6000000000-600fffffff memory:6010000000-6011ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6012000000-6012ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the switcher works with Ubuntu? A good question to ask the maker of the switch.

Comment: Support: "connecting your laptop (running Ubuntu) DP/HDMI output to the IN1806 should work normally".